# Confluence Macro Development in SDK6

Tags: confluence

I am kind of frustrated. I am trying to develop a simple "hello world" macro for confluence. But all the tutorials are not really working anymore for the actual SDK6.

I tried this tutorial:

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/tutorials/macro-tutorials-for-confluence/creating-a-new-confluence-macro#CreatingaNewConfluenceMacro-Step1.Createthepluginprojectandtrimtheskeleton

But as you can see the article discussing, it is not working correctly anymore. I think some elements have be modified with SDK6 and the tutorials are not up to date anymore.

I ask at the confluence-forum for help but without any luck. There are several post around this issue without any solution.

The problem is, that the addon / plugin is visible in the system administration panel but I can not use the macro on a page and I can not see the macro in the macro browser.

**Now it works - Update**

This is what I did:

**1) Download SDK**

I downloaded sdk-installer-6.2.4.exe and installed it

**2) Creating new plugin**

I created a new plugin for confluence by typing in

```
 atlas-create-confluence-plugin
```

with these following group- and artifact ids

```
groupid    : com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence
artifactid : tutorial-confluence-macro-demo
version    : 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package    : package    com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence
```

**3) Creating eclipse project**

Then I created the eclipse project by typing in

```
atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

**4) Modify pom.xml**

I modified the pom.xml just like ppasler explained in his answer. I also modified the companyname and the version in order to check in confluence, if the modification will have an effect. The pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial-confluence-macro-demo</artifactId>
    <version>4.4-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <name>Hauke Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <name>tutorial-confluence-macro-demo</name>
    <description>This is the com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence:tutorial-confluence-macro-demo plugin for Atlassian Confluence.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
            <version>${confluence.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>

                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.api,
                        </Export-Package>

                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                            org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                            *
                        </Import-Package>

                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <properties>
    <confluence.version>5.9.7</confluence.version>
    <confluence.data.version>5.9.7</confluence.data.version>
    <amps.version>6.2.4</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>1.1.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
     <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.6</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
    </properties>
<!--
    <properties>
        <confluence.version>5.9.7</confluence.version>
        <confluence.data.version>5.9.7</confluence.data.version>
        <amps.version>6.2.3</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.6</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
    </properties>
-->
</project>
```

**5) Starting eclipse**

I imported the project to Eclilpse

```
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200
Java JDK 1.8.0_60
```

**6) ExampleMacro class creating**

I created the class "ExampleMacro"

```
package com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence;

import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.ConversionContext;
import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.XhtmlException;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.Macro;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.MacroExecutionException;
import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.MacroDefinition;
import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.MacroDefinitionHandler;
import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.XhtmlContent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleMacro implements Macro
{
    private final XhtmlContent xhtmlUtils;

    public ExampleMacro(XhtmlContent xhtmlUtils)
    {
        this.xhtmlUtils = xhtmlUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute(Map<String, String> parameters, String bodyContent, ConversionContext conversionContext) throws MacroExecutionException
    {
        String body = conversionContext.getEntity().getBodyAsString();

        final List<MacroDefinition> macros = new ArrayList<MacroDefinition>();

        try
        {
            xhtmlUtils.handleMacroDefinitions(body, conversionContext, new MacroDefinitionHandler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(MacroDefinition macroDefinition)
                {
                    macros.add(macroDefinition);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (XhtmlException e)
        {
            throw new MacroExecutionException(e);
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("<p>");
        if (!macros.isEmpty())
        {
            builder.append("<table width=\"50%\">");
            builder.append("<tr><th>Macro Name</th><th>Has Body?</th></tr>");
            for (MacroDefinition defn : macros)
            {
                builder.append("<tr>");
                builder.append("<td>").append(defn.getName()).append("</td><td>").append(defn.hasBody()).append("</td>");
                builder.append("</tr>");
            }
            builder.append("</table>");
        }
        else
        {
            builder.append("You've done built yourself a macro! Nice work.");
        }
        builder.append("</p>");

        return builder.toString();

    }

    @Override
    public BodyType getBodyType()
    {
        return BodyType.NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputType getOutputType()
    {
        return OutputType.BLOCK;
    }
}
```

**7) Modified the atlassian-plugin.xml file**

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    </plugin-info>

    <!-- add our i18n resource -->
    <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="tutorial-confluence-macro-demo"/>

    <xhtml-macro name="tutorial-confluence-macro-demo" class="com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.ExampleMacro" key="my-macro">
        <parameters/>
    </xhtml-macro>

    <!-- add our web resources -->
    <web-resource key="tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-resources" name="tutorial-confluence-macro-demo Web Resources">
        <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>

        <resource type="download" name="tutorial-confluence-macro-demo.css" location="/css/tutorial-confluence-macro-demo.css"/>
        <resource type="download" name="tutorial-confluence-macro-demo.js" location="/js/tutorial-confluence-macro-demo.js"/>
        <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>

        <context>tutorial-confluence-macro-demo</context>
    </web-resource>

</atlassian-plugin>
```

**8) Starting confluence**

```
atlas-clean
atlas-package
atlas-debug
```

**9) Logged into confluence**

Here the result of the confluence administration page

[image: Confluence Administration Page]

And now I can find it also in the macro browser and it works

[image]

Thanks
Hauke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working with atlassian plugins can be really frustrating :)

I checked out the macro [source code from bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/confluence-macro-plugin-tutorial/branch/macro-master) and made the following changes in the pom

```
<properties>
    <confluence.version>5.9.7</confluence.version>
    <confluence.data.version>5.9.7</confluence.data.version>
    <amps.version>6.2.4</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>1.1.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
</properties>
```

Then run

```
atlas-clean
atlas-package
atlas-debug
```

After that I was able to add the macro with the macro browser (with a confluence 5.8.6 instance).

Unfortunatly I had no time to check the differences between the source code and the tutorial, but my solution will give you a working state to try new stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. I edited my post with the steps I did. Many greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Your image is displaying `${atlassian.plugin.key}`. Is your Macro add-on working properly. It is displayed in the macro browser but can you use it on the page? I also noticed you commented out `atlassian.plugin.key` in your `pom.xml`.

> The use of <Atlassian-Plugin-Key> here tells the plugin system that you are a transformerless plugin and that it should skip the slow transformation step. This is VERY IMPORTANT. Without this entry in your Manifest, the plugin system will try to transform your plugin, and you will lose the load time speed benefits. You are also likely to see Spring-related errors. Do not forget to specify this entry.

See: [Atlassian Spring Scanner](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner/src/1.2.x/README.md?at=1.2.x&fileviewer=file-view-default)

The new way of importing components is to use Atlassian Spring Scanner. It looks like your mixing the old and new way of importing components by commenting out `atlassian.plugin.key`.

Check out: [Build a Macro Add-on](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/atlassian/how-to-build-a-macro-add-on-for-atlassian-confluence-server/)

Confluence examples: [Confluence Add-on Development examples](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/author/joel-llosa/)